# MySQL JOIN/AGGREGATE function output

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables in my database :

select * from marks;

[image]

select * from subjects;

[image]

I need to find the id of the students who got the highest marks in each subject along with the subject name, i.e., Resultset should have 3 columns:

| student_id | subject_name | maximum_marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PHYSICS | 97.5 |
| 2 | CHEMSITRY | 98.5 |

Please help me write the query for the above result set

This is what I've tried so far

select m.student_id, s.subject_name, max(m.marks) as maximum_marks from
marks m inner join subjects s
on m.subject_id=s.subject_id
group by m.subject_id;

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  This is clearly homework, and SO is not a code writing service.  First, you make a good faith attempt to solve the problem, then share with us if it doesn't work.

Comment: And, by the way, this is not hard.  First, produce a JOIN query that produces student_id, subject_name and marks.  Easy.  From there, you just have to change it to `MAX(marks) AS maximum_marks` with a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: select m.student_id, s.subject_name, max(m.marks) as maximum_marks from
marks m inner join subjects s
on m.subject_id=s.subject_id
group by s.subject_id;

I've used the above query, but student_id column is 1 in both rows.

Comment: what do you want if there is a tie?  what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 8.0.22 -> mysql version
You can assume there is no tie for this case.

Comment: You have to group by everything that's not an aggregate:  student_id and subject_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e38b79/7)

```
select m.student_id, s.subject_name, m.max_marks
from subjects s join (
 select student_id,subject_id, max(marks) as max_marks 
 from marks 
 group by student_id,subject_id
 order by 3 desc
) as m
on s.subject_id = m.subject_id 
group by s.subject_id
```

**Schema & sample** & `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `marks` (
  `student_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(6)  NOT NULL,
  `marks` float NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subjects` (
  `subject_id` int(6)  NOT NULL,
  `subject_name` varchar(10)  NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `marks` (`student_id`, `subject_id`, `marks`) VALUES
(1,1,97.5),(1,2,92.5),
(2,1,90.5),(2,2,98.5),
(3,1,90.5),(3,2,67.5),
(4,1,80.5),(4,2,97.5);

INSERT INTO `subjects` (`subject_id`, `subject_name`) VALUES
(2,"Chemistry"),(1,"Physics");
```

Comment: Thanks, so we cannot have an output without an inner query?

Comment: @SRIHARSHASVS I usually prefer subquery as its easy to handle try `select m.student_id, s.subject_name, m.marks as maximum_marks from marks m LEFT OUTER JOIN marks AS m2 ON m.student_id = m2.student_id AND m.marks > m2.marks inner join subjects s on m.subject_id=s.subject_id group by m.subject_id`

Comment: Thanks akshay, this helps, meanwhile can you have a look at my solution, I think we can achieve this in a relatively simple manner.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a little bit better solution, this is a common use-case of correlated sub-queries, the output can be achieved without a group-by.

```
select m1.student_id, m1.subject_id, m1.marks, s.subject_name
from marks m1 inner join subjects s
on m1.subject_id=s.subject_id
where m1.marks= 
(select max(marks) from marks m2 where m1.subject_id=m2.subject_id);
```